# Pop "Choose Just-In-Time Debugger" window when I use Roslyn Source Generator

Tags: c#, debugging, roslyn

Is there anyone who use roslyn source generator get the same situation?
Every time when I open source generator project, the window will pop up.
I know that I need to choose debugger manual currently,
but when I use rider, It still shown up!

Any suggestion here? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a component of Resharper is crashing, you'll want to follow up with JetBrains to see if they have a newer version available with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running unit tests in Rider and the solution was :

Settings > Build > Unit Testing > Test Runner > Uncheck "Enable Debug"